# R_user not defined , rpy2

Tags: django, r, python-2.7, rpy2

I want to use R from django app .Now I am in a huge mess .

--> I have installed rpy2 for that .
---> I am able to run everything from Python IDE 
eg .

```
import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
rinterface.initr()
```

or

```
import rpy2.robjects as something
```

As I open Python from cmd or in django file .I am getting error **R_USER not defined**

I am able to write separate .py files and access R but not from django and python shell .

Please help me Out!!!!

Or please tell what else I can use to call R functions from Python

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new system variable `R_USER` in `Environment Variables`, with its value being the current user name, and the problem should goes away.

***Note, this is clearly for windows platform only.***

Otherwise you won't get `R_USER` exception in the first place.